# Transfer XBT between Kraken accounts

Tags: transactions, exchanges, kraken

I have to receive an amount of XBT from a relative. Both of us have a Kraken account. Can I achieve this inside Kraken or do I need any external wallet or similar? If I can do it in Kraken, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do internal transfers within Kraken, but you can [create a deposit address](https://www.kraken.com/u/funding/deposit) and send it to your relative. Then your relative can [withdraw their money](https://www.kraken.com/u/funding/withdraw) in Kraken to the address you provided. Make sure it's the same cryptocurrency! Hope that helps :)

Comment: Would it work if I withdrew XBT from one Kraken account immediately into another? Or should it first go through a personally owned wallet?

Comment: Links you provided are no longer available, but both point to Kraken, so if we can't transfer money between Kraken accounts, how does your method work?